# Comma decimal separator turns into dot after Print code

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I'm having trouble with this code:

It is so weird problem. After I print report, I just lose european keyboard layout, numerical side of keyboard, comma goes into dot. But only inside Excel, not Outlook, not inside Windows
 And only after printing on paper. When I choose to cancel print in PrintPreview there is no error.

Also asked on: 
 http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=199847

< http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/946528-comma-decimal-separator-turns-into-dot-after-copy-code.html

```html
Sub print_fuel_report()
'
' PRINT_fuel_report Macro
'
    On Error GoTo ifERROR
    'This is in case if selected out of print range but clicking print in cell("V1")
        If ActiveCell.Column() > 21 Or ActiveCell.Row() > 61 Or ActiveCell.Row() = 1 _
        Or ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "   W R O N G  RANGE!" & vbNewLine & " " & vbNewLine & _
        "   or there is no print data !", 64, ""
        GoTo ifERROR
        Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim MSG As String, ANS As Variant
        MSG = " DO YOU WANT PRINT REPORT?" & "  " & _
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row) & "  " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row)
        ANS = MsgBox(MSG, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Print report")
        Select Case ANS
            Case vbYes
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
            Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
            Application.UseSystemSeparators = False

            Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("C4").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("C6").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("C7").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("C9").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("K9").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F16").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("H14").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row & ":K" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("G12").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F18").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F19").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row & ":Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("G13").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("R" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F17").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F21").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("T" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("F22").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("List1").Select
            Range("U" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("List2").Select
            Range("H16:J19").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll DOWN:=-30
            Range("A1:L30").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '        In case there is no printing device:
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
            Selection.PrintOut Preview:=True
            On Error GoTo 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            Range("H16:J19").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("F22").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("F21").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("F19").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("F18").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("F16:F17").Select
            Range("F17").Activate
            Selection.ClearContents
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll DOWN:=-18
            Range("G12:J14").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("K9").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("C9").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("C7").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("C6").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Range("C4").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Sheets("List1").Select
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=12
            Range("A1").Select

            Application.UseSystemSeparators = True

            Case vbNo
            GoTo QUIT:
            End Select
ifERROR:
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
QUIT:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you restart Excel?

Comment: When i run Print code i get "dot" num keyboard problem. Then i need to restart excel. Or i can continue work inside workbook but with dot on numerical side of keyboard.

Comment: I posted a solution.  In theory it should work, but let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** After running a macro to print a report, the keyboard configuration malfunctions until the Excel Application is restarted.

**Solution:**

- Create a temporary copy of the workbook
- Create another instance of Excel.Application
- Open the temporary workbook in the new instance of Excel.Application
- Run the macro from the new instance of Excel.Application

**Update - Instructions:** 
Insert this code into the same code module as `print_fuel_report`.  You'll no longer run `print_fuel_report` directly.  Instead run `RunMacroInBackUpCopy`.  It will run `print_fuel_report` in another instance of Excel Application for you.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub RunMacroInBackUpCopy()
        Const PASSWORD As String = ""

        Dim TempFileName As String
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        TempFileName = getTempFileName(ThisWorkbook.Name)

        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs TempFileName

        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TempFileName, PASSWORD:=PASSWORD)

        xlApp.Run "'" & xlWB.Name & "'!print_fuel_report"

        xlWB.Close False
        xlApp.Quit

        Kill TempFileName

        Set xlWB = Nothing
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End Sub

    Function getTempFileName(s As String) As String
        getTempFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempWorkBook." & Right(s, Len(s) - InStrRev(s, "."))
    End Function
```

Comment: •HOW Create a temporary copy of the workbook  
•HOW Create another instance of Excel.Application  
•Open the temporary workbook in the new instance of Excel.Application  
•FROM WHERE(module or..) Run the macro from the new instance of Excel.Application

Comment: I added some instructions to my answer.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Problem still persist, now i have 5 sec print delay.                                     Here is original code:

Answer (score 0):

```html
    Option Explicit

    Sub RunMacroInBackUpCopy()
        Const PASSWORD As String = ""

        Dim TempFileName As String
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        TempFileName = getTempFileName(ThisWorkbook.Name)

        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs TempFileName

        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TempFileName, PASSWORD:=PASSWORD)

        xlApp.Run "'" & xlWB.Name & "'!pRINTA_IZVJESTAJ_GORIVA"

        xlWB.Close False
        xlApp.QUIT

        Kill TempFileName

        Set xlWB = Nothing
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End Sub

    Function getTempFileName(s As String) As String
        getTempFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempWorkBook." & Right(s, Len(s) - InStrRev(s, "."))
    End Function
    
Sub pRINTA_IZVJESTAJ_GORIVA()
'
' PRINTA_IZVJESTAJ_GORIVA Macro
'
On Error GoTo AkoGRESKA
'Ovo ako se klikne negdje van raspona a odabere se printer("V1")
    If ActiveCell.Column() > 21 Or ActiveCell.Row() > 61 Or ActiveCell.Row() = 1 _
    Or ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "   K R I V I   R A S P O N !" & vbNewLine & " " & vbNewLine & _
    "   ILI NEMA PODATAKA ZA ISPIS !", 64, ""
    GoTo AkoGRESKA
    Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim MSG As String, ANS As Variant
    MSG = " ŽELITE  LI  ISPISATI  IZVJEŠTAJ  ULAZA?" & "  " & _
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row) & "  " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row)
    ANS = MsgBox(MSG, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Ispis izvještaja")
    Select Case ANS
        Case vbYes
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("C4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("C6").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("C7").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("C9").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("K9").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F16").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("H14").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row & ":K" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("G12").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F18").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row & ":Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("G13").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("R" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F17").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F21").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("T" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("F22").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("List1").Select
        Range("U" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("List2").Select
        Range("H16:J19").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll DOWN:=-30
        Range("A1:L30").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
'        U slučaju da nema printera:
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
        Selection.PrintOut Preview:=True
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Range("H16:J19").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F22").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F21").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F19").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F18").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F16:F17").Select
        Range("F17").Activate
        Selection.ClearContents
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll DOWN:=-18
        Range("G12:J14").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("K9").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("C9").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("C7").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("C6").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("C4").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Sheets("List1").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=12
        Range("A1").Select
        
        Case vbNo
        GoTo QUIT:
        End Select
AkoGRESKA:
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
QUIT:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Workbook name:Ulaz GORIVO.xlsm

Comment: Workbook has three sheets, two of them are password protected. So you think problem might be 'cause sheets are protected? Why the hell password affects keyboard layout?!

Comment: Can someone or do someone know vba code to unlock and upon code completion to lock sheet? I do think that my problem with dot might be because two of the workbook sheets are password protected :(

Comment: NO NO, problem still persist, I unlocked all sheets and tried to print, and error again. Again comma from numerical keyboard turned into dot!  AARRRRRGGGHHHHH!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out after three months. Problem is in PrintPreview, but **WHYYY MICROSOFT, WHY!**

'        In case there is no printing device:
         On Error Resume Next
         Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
         Selection.PrintOut Preview:=True

When i set Selection.PrintOut Preview:=False  **everything is fine, no error.**

But, why! I really need print preview :(  ;(